# How do I resolve HttpContext from a RegisterEvent to retrieve a View in a string in asp.net core 3and Electron.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, electron.net

I've tried Dependency injection, but that always gives me a `HttpContextAccessor.Current` or `ActionContext` as null because I'm not in a request state (I think). So how can I get this context to just take a view, transform it to a html string (with Model if necessary) and throw it back in JS ? I even tried to call directly the Controller action, but it always gives HttpContext as null... I'm using Asp.NET Core 3.

Please, if someone has been going through, help me :-)

Thanks,

Edit:

I have an asp.net core based on Electron.net for a desktop application. I use a lot of IPC communication to retrieve data from backend c# using `Electron.IpcMain.On`. I register an action as listener in c# in a class. The main problem is that this class is really outside a normal HttpRequest or a Controller. Here is some sample code:

IpcBase Class

```
public abstract class IpcBase: IBaseIpcCommunicationClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Find a way to get rid of this and take more than the first window
        /// </summary>
        protected static BrowserWindow _mainWindow = Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First();
        /// <summary>
        /// Send an ipcEvent with a parameter class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameters">Parameters to fill</param>
        public void RegisterIpcEvent<T>(IpcRegisterModel<T> registerModel) => Electron.IpcMain.On(registerModel.key, o => registerModel.action((T)
            ((JObject)o).ToObject(typeof(T))));

        /// <summary>
        /// Send a reply inside a registerevent
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of model</typeparam>
        /// <param name="model">model</param>
        public void SendReply<T>(IpcSendParamsModel<T> model)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.replyTo))
            {
                Electron.IpcMain.Send(_mainWindow, model.replyTo, model);
            }
        }
...
}
```

IpcUI (to get the controller view, just like an ajax call on a controller that retrieve the view in String (I already have that, but not with Ipc)

```
public class IpcUI: IpcBase
    {
        public IpcUI(IRazorViewToStringService razorViewRenderService)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IpcUI::Constructor");
            RegisterIpcEvent(new IpcRegisterModel<IpcSendParamsModel<AjaxPartialModel>>("renderPartial", async (param) =>
            {                
            var param = new IpcSendParamsModel<AjaxPartialModel>("RenderPartial")
            {
                key = "renderPartial",
                model = new AjaxPartialModel()
                {
                    DataModel = "{items: [{\r\n            MaterialIcon: \"\",\r\n            Title: \"Games\",\r\n            Selectable: true,\r\n            Active: true,\r\n            Key: \"GAMES\",\r\n            BadgeCaption: \"new\",\r\n            BadgeValue: \"123\",\r\n            BadgeColor: \"red darken-1\",\r\n            BadgePartialLink: \"\",\r\n            BadgeContainerLink: \"\",\r\n            BadgeModelLink: \"\",\r\n            PartialLink: \"Home/Index\",\r\n            ContainerLink: \"#body-content\",\r\n            ModelLink: \"\"\r\n        }] }".JsonDeserialize<MenuModelHeader>(),
                    PartialName = "PartialViews/_TopMenu"
                }
            };

            try
            {                
                param.results =
                    await razorViewRenderService.CreateAndResolveInstanceFromGeneric().RenderViewToStringAsync($"~/Views/{param.model.PartialName}.cshtml",
                        param.model.DataModel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                IpcClasses.ExceptionManager.SendException(this, e, $"IpcUI params: {param.model.JsonSerialize()}");
            }
            }));
        }
}
```

Razor Service (Mostly taken from here [Generate string from view](http://%20https://dotnetstories.com/blog/Generate-a-HTML-string-from-cshtml-razor-view-using-ASPNET-Core-that-can-be-used-in-the-c-controlle-7173969632))

Added in startup:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<IRazorViewToStringService, RazorRazorViewToStringService>();
```

When I create an instance of IpcUI, DI gives me the service, but without any HttpContext or ActionContext... Sorry for the lack of information from my last edit :-). Hope it is a bit more specific.

Oh ! I forgot something, IpcUI is created at runtime not with a new (because that don't work) but with a custom extension function that retrieves the IServiceProvider for DI:

In startup

```
ExtensionsUtils.ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices;
```

In ExtensionsUtils

```
/// <summary>
        /// This is called in configure services to get the collection of services in an extension static class
        /// </summary>
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a reference from type T with DI
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="o"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T CreateAndResolveInstanceFromGeneric<T>(this T o)
        {
            return (T)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(ServiceProvider);
        }
```

Edit 2:
I have tried to access `IRazorViewToStringService` from a real controller constructor and it's null again... What Am I doing wrong ???

```
private readonly IRazorViewToStringService _razorViewRenderService;

        public BaseController(IRazorViewToStringService razorViewRenderService)
        {
            _razorViewRenderService = razorViewRenderService;
        }
...
/// <summary>
        /// Return a success http code and a View rendered as string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ViewName">Name of MVC View (or PartialView)</param>
        /// <param name="Model">Model to pass if any</param>
        /// <returns>JSON: { result: "type", description: "Html Code" }</returns>
        public async Task<ActionResult> CheckAndReturnView(string ViewName, object Model = null)
        {
            return Ok(await _razorViewRenderService.RenderViewToStringAsync(ViewName, Model)); 
        }
```

Comment: Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry, hope this will help